# Meaning of "all the way" in "all the way on the right"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In this dialogue:

> Which one is your mother?
>   *The one **all the way** on the right.*

I don’t get the meaning of “all the way”.
Does that mean on the distance?

Answer (score 4):

In a picture like this one:

[image]

The *leftmost* person (Person A) is said to be "**all the way to the left**," while the person furthest to the right (Person D) can be said to be "**all the way on the right.**"

**Note**: both prepositions (*to* and *on*) are grammatical, and you don't have to use *to* with *left*, or *on* with *right*.

Therefore, you wouldn't use the expression "all the way on the right" to describe the location of your mother unless there happened to be other people to the left of her, and no one on her right.